# Resolving namespace conflict with satellite assembly

Tags: c#

I have a satellite assembly in my project called `Localization`. I also have an MVC project which contains the following model:

```
namespace MvcApp.Models.Localization {
    class Model {
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetLocalization() {
            // I want to access the Localization assembly here...
            Assembly localization = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Localization.Viewer));
            // I'm getting a conflict here as i'm currently inside a Localization
            // namespace
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a nice way I can access the **assembly** `Localization` in this context, rather than the current namespace?

I'm happy enough to rename the Model namespace, but wanted to know if there is a better way.

Comment: why dont you try full name of assembly

Comment: @PranayRana `Localization` is literally the full name of the assembly - unless there's a prefix/suffix notation I'm not aware of

Comment: thank i guess answer given by @Ricky is correct in this case ...you can try that solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that i understood you problem but a suggestion is to use Namespace Alias:
On top you import namespace with Alias like below

```
using first = FirstNamespace;
```

And then you could access the class you want like that:

```
first.Test test = new first.Test();
```